# increase loader width of a svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I tried to increase the spinning width of a circle svg but failed, any idea which value to adjust?

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#3b5998" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `stroke` and `stroke-width` attributes to increase the width of spinning area like this:

```
<svg ...>
     <path ... stroke="#3b5998" stroke-width="5"></path>
</svg>
```

the path must have `stoke` attribute to let path increases width using `stroke-width`.

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve" >
  <path stroke="#3b5998" d="m43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z" stroke-width="5">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
    
  
</div>
```

**EDIT:** you can also use custom image background as stroke like this:

```
<svg ...>
 <defs>
    <pattern id="p1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="32" height="32">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIXg7.jpg" width="32" height="32" />
    </pattern>
 </defs>
 <path ... stroke="url(#p1)" stroke-width="5"></path>
</svg>
```

```html
<div class="loader">
  
    <svg version="1.1" id="loader-2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="30px" height="30px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve" >
    <defs>
    <pattern id="p1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="32" height="32">
      <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIXg7.jpg" width="32" height="32" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <path stroke="url(#p1)" d="m43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z" stroke-width="5">
    
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
    
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to apply background to the circle?

Comment: @AliciaBrandon,yes that's possible, I updated the answer for your new request.

Answer (score 0):

I changed from `width="30px" height="30px"` to `width="300px" height="300px"`. I'm not 100% sure this is what you meant though:

```html
<div class="loader">
  <svg version="1.1" id="loader-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="enable-background:new 0 0 50 50;" xml:space="preserve">
  <path fill="#3b5998" d="M43.935,25.145c0-10.318-8.364-18.683-18.683-18.683c-10.318,0-18.683,8.365-18.683,18.683h4.068c0-8.071,6.543-14.615,14.615-14.615c8.072,0,14.615,6.543,14.615,14.615H43.935z">
    <animateTransform attributeType="xml"
      attributeName="transform"
      type="rotate"
      from="0 25 25"
      to="360 25 25"
      dur="0.6s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </path>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: the width increase when the size increase, I just want to increase the width.

Comment: Ah, the SVG data it's self probably has to be modified then. Inside of that `d=` attribute. Perhaps best left to a vector based editor like [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/en/), though I'm not sure on it's animation abilities.